# Como faço para o xcopy copiar um diretório de uma variavel

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, windows-10, bat

Estou com um projeto envolvendo bat más eu preciso usar um comando (xcopy)

Supondo:
Eu quero que eu possa digitar o diretório inteiro 
ex: 
C:\Users\"User"\diretoriocopia

e poder digitar o destino 
ex:
D:\Diretoriodestino

Comment: Questões de suporte não se encaixam no escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Se tiver facilidade com inglês, pode usar o site [su] que é para questões de suporte (infelizmente não conseguimos uma versão em português desse).

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Para digitar o diretório, use o comando **`set /p`** :

Ele abre um entrada para que você possa **inserir/digar** o que deseja ir para a variável:

---

```bat
set /p _nome_variável=

rem :: Opcionalmente, pode incluir um texto para exibição junto do comando, exemplo ::

set /p "_nome_variável=Texto para exibição: "
```

> - Um exemplo de uso do comando **`set /p`** já adaptado numa sugestão de uso com o **`xcopy`**

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title <nul
mode 91,10 & color 0a & title Q420630.cmd & cd. & echo=

set /p "_dir_Origem= Digite Um Diretorio Origem: " && (
dir /d "!_dir_Origem!" | findstr /l \[\.\.\] > nul && (
set /p "_dir_Destino= Digite Um Diretorio de Destino: "

if not "!_dir_Destino!\\" == "\\" goto :^? ) ) || echo= 
echo= Revise os seus argumentos/parâmetros informados:
echo= "!_dir_Origem!"  "!_dir_Origem!" & exit /b  ...

:^?
xcopy /c /y /e /v /f /i "!_dir_Origem!" "!_dir_Destino!"
```

---

> - Comentando o código usado...
>
>   ---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title <nul

:: redimensiona tela para x/y 91 colunas e 10 linhas ::
:: muda cor para fundo preto, texto verde e adiciona ::
:: altera titulo para janela aberta, e ecoa 2 linhas :: 
mode 91,10 & color 0a & title Q420630.cmd & cd. & echo=

:: Set /p para aguardar inserção de caminho/diretório :: 
set /p "_dir_Origem= Digite Um Diretório Origem: " && (

:: Apenas para verificar se pasta passada é existente ::
dir /d "!_dir_Origem!" | findstr /l \[\.\.\] > nul && (

:: Após verificado que existe, pede um pasta destino  ::
set /p "_dir_Destino= Digite Um Diretorio de Destino: " 

if not "!_dir_Destino!\\" == "\\" goto :^? ) ) || echo= 

:: Para agir em caso de inconsistência nos parâmetros  
echo= Revise os seus argumentos/parâmetros informados:

echo= "!_dir_Origem!"  "!_dir_Origem!" & exit /b  ...

:^?
xcopy /c /y /e /v /f /i "!_dir_Origem!" "!_dir_Destino!"

::  Seu comando para a tarefa do XCOPY, entrar aqui!  ::
::  Comando acima é só um exemplo de uso/teste aqui.  ::

echo= xcopy [seus argumentos/parâmetros] "!_dir_Origem!" "!_dir_Destino!"
```

> - Para obter mais ajuda acerca dos comandos utilizados nessa resposta:
> - Copie e execute na linha de comando:

```bat
chcp 860 & > "%temp%\help_comandos.txt" (set /? & dir /? & xcopy /? & findstr /? * title /? & setlocal /? & mode /?) & "%temp%\help_comandos.txt"
```

> - Esse código vai gera um arquivo (**help_comandos.txt**), já contendo o texto de ajuda sobre os comandos utilizados na resposta postada.
> - Salve esse arquivo para vossas consultas futuras..

---

---